# Return from mysql using procedure and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `verifLogin`(INOUT `email` VARCHAR(75), INOUT `password` VARCHAR(30))
READS SQL DATA
SELECT * FROM tblLogon WHERE emailLogon = email and passwordLogon = password$$
DELIMITER ;

try{
        $email = $_POST['emailLog'];
        $password = $_POST['passwordLog'];

        $sql = "CALL verifLogin (?, ?)";

        $stmt = $PDO -> prepare($sql);

        $stmt -> bindParam(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 75);
        $stmt -> bindParam(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);

        $stmt -> execute();

        $row = (int) $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($row > 0){
            $res = array("erro" => "false", "message" => "Ok!");
        }
        else{
            $res = array("erro" => "true", "message" => "Fail! ");
        }
        echo $res['message'];

    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        echo $exc -> getTraceAsString();
}
```

It's a login code, I am not getting a return from mysql, every time I try another way the error message is the same, the connection is ok, but I don't receive nothing from mysql

Comment: That all looks like a bad idea (mostly because of storing plain passwords). But you probably just need `if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) ...`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I've tried it and it doens't works, I receive "Fail!" from my code.

Comment: `var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));` and see what you get.

Comment: Didn't work too